# Is it possible to develop stuff for Oculus Rift without owning one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Sadly, I don't own a Oculus Rift nor would I be able to afford one in near future. Yet, I'd really like to add Oculus Rift support to a game (using Unity3D) and I'd like to know whether or not it is possible to do so without owning one.
Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, as you can download the SDK for free from the [Oculus website](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/).

However, you won't be able to test that it works properly so you'd be at risk of shipping functionality that may be buggy or completely broken. For this reason I'd recommend against it.

Comment: I'd have a few people who could test it and I could also get my hands on one, although this would only be possible occasionally. Well, maybe I should just try to get one somehow..